# can Adobe Flash CS6 export for mobile correctly?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, air, flash-cs6

I have developed some mini games with adobe flash, I want to port this games for mobile (Android and IOS) but after a few search I figued out none of them support flash programs. I choosed flash platform for portability but it seems it is not portable at all.
I searched for other adobe flash versions that support this feature and found this product:
http://huhirbsbwsntyudp.appstorelux.com/product/adobe-creative-suite-6-master-collection-64-bit/

In feature list of this version, below feature mentioned:

•   Mobile platform and device support in Flash Professional

•   Create content in Flash Professional for delivery across a wide variety of       devices with support for the Flash Player 11.2 and Adobe AIR® 3.2 runtimes; and for platforms including iOS, Android™, and Adobe Digital Home.

But iOS and Android said they won’t support flash files! Which one is correct? Has anybody tested it before, I mean develop game with flash and publish it for iOS or Android? Currently, SWF files of my project doesn’t work on any mobile device.

Sorry for poor language,
thanks

Comment: You cannot deploy flash content to iOS or Android market place. But you can convert your apps to AS3 Mobile Projects and export them as native iPA or Apk apps which you can publish to PlayStore or Apple AppStore.

Comment: thanks for your replay, is it easy to convert my apps to actionScript mobile project? I have 12 apps that I should convert them, how much time I should spend for that and is it reasonable to convert them or it is better to develop them from base? another question, is actionScript mobile project included in Flash professional or another product?

Comment: You can find more details on official Adobe website or in stackoverflow. http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2012/12/ios-apps-flash-cs6.html   Conversion time depends on the projects complexity but should be not so difficult.

Comment: swf is for Flash Player in-browser which is what got blocked on mobile.  Get Flash CC, it publishes native IOS apps and Android apps using AIR.  Many top games in both iTunes and Play were created in Flash.  gotoandlearn.com has great video tutorials to get started.